# PBM_SETMARQUEE is not working for vertical processbars?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, win32gui

I'm searching and testing already a lot of time on this problem and I still can’t get PBM_SETMARQUEE for vertical processbars working. It always show me a completely green filled processbar but no moving green "rectangle" from the bottom to the top. Somehow if I remove the PBS_VERTICAL style then I get a horizontal processbar with a moving green "rectangle „from left to right. So means the PBM_SETMARQUEE works for horizontal processbar but not for vertical. Something I also figured out is if I disable the windowtheme style for the processbar the PBM_SETMARQUEE suddenly works O_o!? (but with no windowstheme color and animation)
Here is the needed part of code (using c++ and winapi):

```
//includes especially for the processbar
#include <CommCtrl.h>  
#include <Uxtheme.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment( lib, "UxTheme.lib")
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

//code how i creat the processbar
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX initCtrlEx;
initCtrlEx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
initCtrlEx.dwICC = ICC_PROGRESS_CLASS;
if (InitCommonControlsEx(&initCtrlEx)){     
    hProcessBar = CreateWindowExA(
        NULL,
        PROGRESS_CLASSA,
        "",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | PBS_VERTICAL,                                         
        10, 10,
        20, 250,
        hParent,
        (HMENU)id,
        hProgrammInstance,
        NULL
        );
}

//SetWindowTheme(hProcessBar, L"", L""); If i use this code then the  PBM_SETMARQUEE for vertical processbar works.. but cause i want the windowTheme style its not a good solution for me
DWORD style = GetWindowLongPtrA(hProcessBar, GWL_STYLE);
SetWindowLongPtrA(hProcessBar, GWL_STYLE, style | PBS_MARQUEE); //enable needed style for the  PBM_SETMARQUEE message. (i also tested it doing it directly in CreateWindowExA())
SendMessageA(hProcessBar, PBM_SETMARQUEE, TRUE, (LPARAM)30);//enable marquee mode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much more to be said. Microsoft did not implement vertical themed marquee progress bars. Presumably they felt that there was no demand for them.

Comment: Thx for your answer David. XD and like always... some pro's hobby seems to be to downvote newbie questions always^^... they never leave a comment why they downvoted the question^^ so how can I know what I’m doing wrong if nobody say it O_o!? …and for sure, before asking here a question I do some research^^ or how would I know for ex. that SetWindowTheme(hProcessBar, L"", L"");  can solve it (but not the way I need) ?